# Can't alter password

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to alter the password of a user in plsql:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN

ALTER USER BOB IDENTIFIED BY PASS123;

END;
```

I keep getting the error when I create it and cannot make it out what it wrong:

> ORA-06550: line 4, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER"
>   when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for
>   goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with   
>   << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm#BJEHDACE)

> Only dynamic SQL can execute the following types of statements within
>   PL/SQL program units:
>
> - Data definition language (DDL) statements such as CREATE, DROP, GRANT,
>     and REVOKE
> - Session control language (SCL) statements such as ALTER SESSION and
>     SET ROLE
> - The TABLE clause in the SELECT statem

```
DECLARE
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER BOB IDENTIFIED BY PASS123';

END;
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL, it works, thank you so much! I can't accept the answer for another 10 minutes.

Comment: @user2924127 I will wait 10min then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDL statements (alter, create, grant etc) without begin-end block.

ALTER USER BOB IDENTIFIED BY PASS123;